# System wide NSUserDefaults in cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, application-settings

I've got an app that will be run by multiple users.  Any of them can change the settings within the app, but everyone needs to see the same settings.  I know that sounds odd, but just go with it.  I also don't need to worry about multiple people changing things at once (again, just go with it :))

What's the right way to store these settings?  Normally I'd use an NSUserDefaults command, but that of course doesn't allow the different users to see the settings.  I was hoping to avoid going the route of making the app setuid to some user.

Answer (score 0):

Write all user settings(NSDictionary) in `plist`(property list) file.

```
[UserSettings writeToFile:commonPlistfilePath atomically:YES]; // UserSettings is NSDictionary
```